# Are there floating-point numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I see many questions about methods to detect if a value is a floating-point number, but none of the examples work on numbers like as 1.0, 5.0, etc.

Is it possible to distinguish between numbers like 1 and 1.0 or 5 and 5.0? If yes, how can you detect a floating-point variable type?

Comment: It’s not possible to distinguish those from regular integers in JavaScript, no. There’s just a `Number` type.

Comment: They're all floating point numbers.  What behavior would you expect?  Does `isFloat(1) == isFloat(1.0)`?

Comment: exactly. I want to get False in current example

Comment: Try read a question. I need do this operation with numbers 1.0, 2.0 and others.

Comment: Try reading your answers, there’s no difference.

Comment: @minitech Try in console var a = 1.0; /\./g.test(a.toString()), and get the false

Comment: If you want, after an asignment, distinguish that what was assigned was 5 and not 5.0, you can't : var x=5; and var x=5.0; will yield very exact same result. If you talk about the strings '5' and '5.0', then a regexp will do the job.

Comment: @Zerstoren then, try by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ecmascript 6, you can use [`isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger):

```
var value = . . .;
Number.isInteger(value);
```

However, this is not widely supported yet. For now, you can use this:

```
function isInteger(value) {
    return typeof value === 'number' && (value | 0) === value;
}
```

This should work for all integer values that can be represented exactly in a 64-bit floating point representation.

Comment: `typeof value` is never `integer`…

Comment: @minitech - Yeah. Fixed that. My mind was on a side track somewhere.

Comment: +1, this is right, but it’s still not possible to distinguish `5.0` from `5`.

Comment: @minitech - Well, as Sniffer points out, 5 and 5.0 are exactly the same set of bits in JavaScript.

Comment: it not working how I expect. isInterger(5.0) === isInteger(5) this is true, and this is bad(((

Comment: @Zerstoren: Did you read the comments at all, on your question, or this answer, or the other answer? Same value.

Comment: @Zerstoren - In JavaScript, 5.0 and 5 are exactly the same value. There is no "integer type" in JS; only `Number`. At best you will be able to distinguish "5" from "5.0" as strings, but once they are numbers, everything is floating point. All you can do is test whether a floating point value happens to be an integer, which is what my answer shows how to do.

Comment: @Zerstoren You are probably trying to solve your problem the wrong way, why do you need to know if a number is float or integer ?

Comment: @Sniffer i get data from mongodb and want to print this data with strong typing.

Comment: That algorithm will determine if the number if round or not (`value == Math.round(value)` would achieve the same thing). But it doesn't distinguish between 5 and 5.0.

Comment: @OliverMoran - Yes, as I made clear in comments responding to OP's comments, 5 and 5.0 are indistinguishable in JS. I also mentioned in a comment that OP would need to rely on a string representation to make the distinction.

Comment: @Zerstoren, if you want to print a number to a fixed number of decimal places use the `toFloat` method. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think the more concise answer is this one :

In javascript : 5 === 5.0.

So from this point on, no way can be found to distinguish them.
They are strictly the same thing.

Edit : reminder : the only x such as (x!==x) in javascript is NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Zerstoren, the others are technically right: in javascript if you enter 2.0 or 2, there is no difference on how data is stored internally, so there is no way to find out if data was originally written as integer or float.

However, in case you want to validate some user form data, so that the user enters only integer numbers (e.g. order 2 pizzas, not 2.0) then the you do have a solution because that's actually a string (hence "2.0" is not same as "2"). You can use

```
typeof(n) =="string" && parseInt(n, 10) == n && n.indexOf('.')==-1
```

The first typeof condition is so that you fall under data is still in string format case I mentioned. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/X6U2d/

Andrei

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a `float` or `int` basic types in JavaScript, only a `number`. So, there is no difference between 5.0 and 5.

If it is important to you (for whatever reason), you will need to store the value as a string then use `parseFloat` to extract the value.

For example:

```
var int = "5";
var float = "5.0";
console.log(int == float); // false
console.log(parseFloat(int) == parseFloat(float)); // true
```

**How to print numbers to fixed number of decimal places**

I've just spotted  Zerstoren comment: "i get data from mongodb and want to print this data with strong typing."

The method [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) can be used to print a number to fixed number of decimal places:

```
var num = 5;
console.log( num.toFixed(1) ); // 5.0
```

Comment: Or you could use `console.log(+int == float);`, which will also print `true`.